# Saving recorded video to photo library - Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, video, swiftycam

Hope you are well.

I am using your SwiftyCam and its very handy to create any simple camera app. The only problem I am having is I can not find any way to save the recorded video to gallery.

I tried this:
**UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url, nil, nil, nil)**

But its giving me this error:
**Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'**

Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to signature

> func UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(_ videoPath: String, 
>                                          _ completionTarget: Any?, 
>                                          _ completionSelector: Selector?, 
>                                          _ contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)

You need to supply video path  as `String` type not `URL` , so you can use `url.path`

Comment: Thank you very much! Working perfectly.